# Bootstrap dropdown doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I'm loading bootstrap into my application via `Meteor add xyz` (not script tag), and the hidden packages file in my project director reads:

```
meteor-platform
autopublish
insecure
twbs:bootstrap
iron:router
bootstrap
accounts-ui
accounts-password
jquery
```

So I definitely have bootstrap working, but when I click on my Bootstrap dropdown menu, or even this 3rd party scrollable dropdown menu:

http://www.bootply.com/86116

The dropdown button gets highlighted around the edges, but nothing drops down.

What's going on here?  I've seen similar posts, but they revolved around people loading multiple twbs compilers in the header. Is it possible that my two bootstrap packages are causing a collision?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be for a packages conflict.

Try removing `meteor remove bootstrap`

and just keep with the `twbs:bootstrap` package.

Something mizzao bootstrap package do the trick

```
meteor add mizzao:bootstrap-3
```

Comment: all I had to do was `meteor remove bootstrap`